# AWS API Gateway : Signature Mismatch when using query params with AWS IAM Auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an GET based API gateway set up pointing to a Lambda with Lambda Proxy integration enabled

The API has AWS IAM as the auth method.

On my local, I have AWS Auth setup with temp session token

The following works without issue

```
curl -s  GET "https://<ID>.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev" \
--header "x-amz-security-token: ${SESSION_TOKEN}" \
--user $ACCESS_KEY:$SECRET_KEY \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-west-2:execute-api" | jq .
```

But when I add query params to the url, it fails

```
curl -s  GET "https://<ID>.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev?a=${v1}&b=${v2}" \
--header "x-amz-security-token: ${SESSION_TOKEN}" \
--user $ACCESS_KEY:$SECRET_KEY \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-west-2:execute-api" | jq .
```

This is the response that I get is

```
{
  "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/dev\nb=def&a=abc\nhost:<ID>.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20230104T112344Z\n\nhost;x-amz-date\<date-token>'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20230104T112344Z\n20230104/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request\<token>'\n"
}
```

Looks like I need to add the query params part to the signature part. How do I do that ? Or is there something else that I'm missing ?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I'm having the same issue and can't seem to find any solutions. Strangely Postman gives the same error even without query param but other urls work fine - just this one that expects query param

Comment: @kmugi I couldn't find a fix for this. Instead made a change of the API type from GET to POST. And then passed the data I needed as json